# ViewStateException at MySite.aspx on personal site creation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, viewstate, mysite

I have a MySite host personalized with a custom master page and a usercontrol with a listview on it.

I'm getting a "This Page has been modified since you opened it" error message when trying to create a personal site for a user. The logs show a ViewStateException.

By removing the usercontrol it works well.

I've also disabled the ViewState (EnableViewState="false") at the page and control level but I didn't have any success.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you are using updating SPWeb object in the user control , which causes such exception.

Please share the code to get a correct answer to the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the personal site collection had a custom master page defined that had Controls with active viewstate.

The solution was to change that master page to the default, since I didn't need a custom master page on the personal site, only on the root site.